# LWC Template Conflicts Breaking Component Without Errors

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying to make a stupid simple LWC:

**JavaScript**

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const CONTACT_FIELDS = ["Contact.Picklist__c"];

const CONSTANT = "constant";

export default class someLWC extends LightningElement {
   @api contactId;

   @track contact;

   @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$contactId', fields: CONTACT_FIELDS})
   getContact({error, data}){
       if (error) {
           // show toast
       } else if (data) {
           // Do stuff (not relevant to the current issue)
       }
   }

   get isConstant() {
       return this.contact.fields.Picklist__c.value === CONSTANT;
   }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <p>undefined</p>
    <template if:true={isConstant}>
        <p>true</p>
    </template>
    <template if:false={isConstant}>
        <p>false</p>
    </template>
</template>
```

LWC is embeded to the home page with a hard-coded contact Id
Viewing the Home page while logged in as a user with Debug Mode Enabled

- Nothing is rendered to the screen (not even the "undefined")
- No errors are present in debug log
- No toast message displayed containing errors
- Also tried using lwc:if and lwc:else and the issue is the same

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the contact is undefined.

```
   get isConstant() {
       return this.contact.fields.Picklist__c.value === CONSTANT;
   }
```

should be

```
   get isConstant() {
       let result;

       if (this.contact) {
           return this.contact.fields.Picklist__c.value === CONSTANT;
       }

       return result;
   }
```

Additionally, this issue can happen if you reference the contact variable directly in the HTML without checking to see if it is null

```
<template>
    <p>undefined</p>
    <template if:true={isConstant}>
        <p>true</p>
    </template>
    <template if:false={isConstant}>
        <p>false</p>
    </template>
</template>
```

should be

```
<template>
    <template if:true={contact}>
        <p>undefined</p>
        <template if:true={isConstant}>
            <p>true</p>
        </template>
        <template if:false={isConstant}>
            <p>false</p>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

This works around what is essentially a null reference error to get the component to work correctly.

It seems SFDC doesn't show errors for referencing undefined variables within getters.

**Posting mostly so that if someone spends a couple hours struggling with a component not rendering but with no errors being thrown they may stumble upon this.**

Comment: P.S. `if:true` and `if:else` should be `lwc:if` and `lwc:else`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use null-check operator to check for null references.

```
       get isConstant() {
           return this.contact?.fields?.Picklist__c?.value === CONSTANT;
       }
```

Comment: No need for the if when you're using the safe navigation operator--that's literally the point of using it.

Comment: ye, you're right, thanks. I rushed it too much before training) I'll update answer and put it into getter